# WordPress/BuddyPress child theme functions.php ignored selectively

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, buddypress

This is puzzling. I have a child theme (with its own custom functions.php) that works fine except for a handful of pages. For some reason, it's like those handful of pages don't recognize the custom functions.php file.

I have the user filling out a BuddyPress registration form - and then have my functions.php file use the bp_after_registration_confirmed hook to update a few things behind the scenes. The bizarre part is that this works exactly as expected in my development environment - with functions.php responding to the BuddyPress hook. But on the live server, it totally ignores that and just completes registration without invoking my custom function.

Any idea what I may be missing?

What could possibly cause the live server to not see/execute the child theme's custom functions.php file in a handful of instances?

-- UPDATE --

I noticed that for the pages that do not see the child theme's functions.php, they do see functions from the parent theme's functions.php file. Weird, right?

Comment: Does the same themes activated? Are BuddyPress versions the same?

Comment: Yeah - they're all the same versions of BuddyPress and of the theme. I checked to verify the environment was a match and that is definitely the case. <p> I also added some debug code to verify that the right page/template was getting called. The one thing that really does confuse me, though, is that the add_action... or add_filter... calls seem to be completely ignored in these cases. It's like the events never get fired. For example, I have a function that uses the bp_after_registration_confirmed hook to output a line of text and it is just never invoked. So frustrating...

Comment: Are they using templates of the parent theme or something related like that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if they are using child theme templates?

If they're using parent theme templates, try creating overriding copies of the same template and see if they then use your child themes functions.php